# Make scrollView lock into certain offsets

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, swipe

First off, I didn't know how to search for this, which is why I posted it as a question. I'm sorry if it's already been asked, I haven't found it.

I want to make a scrollView look like the App Drawer, so it has 3 possible offsets (like screen).

Here's my code what I tried, but this only works if I drag and not take up my finger till scrolling ends, but doesn't end if I swipe:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 640)
{
    if (oldOffset == 0)
    {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 100 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < 420)
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 320;
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 420)
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(640, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 640;
        }
        else
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
        }
    }
    else if (oldOffset == 320)
    {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 220)
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 0;
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 420)
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(640, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 640;
        }
        else
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:NO];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 220) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 0;
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 540) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:NO];
            oldOffset = 320;
        }
        else
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(640, 0) animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What about `pagingEnabled` property of `UIScrollView`? Doesn't it satisfy your needs?

Comment: Well, that was an easy fix :|

Comment: Which means? Was that what you were trying to do? :-) If so, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Too bad I couldn't formulate my question better.

Comment: I'm glad I have helped. Also, I have posted the answer, so please accept my answer as a little appreciation, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `UIScrollView`'s property `pagingEnabled` to `YES`. When enabled, scroll view will automatically "snap" scrolling to multiples of its size (width for horizontal scrolling, height for vertical scrolling)

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) says:

> **pagingEnabled**
>
> If the value of this property is `YES`, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls. The default value is `NO`.